# Multi-columns. Distribution and horizontal lines

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I got table, which, for the sake of brevity I dumbed down to the following,

```
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l|c c c|l|l|l| }
    \hline
    Problem $I_k$ & Solved $C_k$ & \multicolumn{3}{ |c| }{Solution to $C_k$} & Current & Pursue & Stored\\
    & & $x_1$ & $x_2$ & $z$ & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

which produces the following output

[image]

Now, I got two questions, both related to the multi-column. First is it possible to generate a partial `\hline` that only affect the third column (Separating the "Solution to C_k" label and the three variables)?

Secondly, it looks like $x_1$, $x_2$ and $z$ are not being centred. How can this be recitifed?

Comment: (i) `\cline{3-5}`, (ii) `\multicolumn{3}{c}{Solution to $C_k$}` is wider than sum of width of spanned columns, consequently column with `$z$` is extended. you should redefine `c` columns, for example to `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{....}`

Comment: (i) thanks! :D (ii) is there any way I can easily size each of the spanned columns as a third of the column spanning them?

Comment: i show in comment haw ... i will write an answer ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

spotted asymmetry of `c` column width arise from fact that `\multicolumn{3}{c}{Solution to $C_k$}` is wider than sum of widths of spanned columns. consequently column contain $z$ is extended to fit width of multi column cell.

to have all `c` columns equal width you had to prescribe their width, for example with help of column type `p{<width>}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% needed for column redefinition
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l|*{3}{C{2em}}|l|l|l| }
    \hline
Problem $I_k$ & Solved $C_k$ & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Solution to $C_k$}
    & Current & Pursue & Stored     \\
    \cline{3-5}
    & & $x_1$ & $x_2$ & $z$ & & & \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

however, i would rather design table on the following way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}% needed for column redefinition and nicer looks
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ ll *{3}{C{2em}} lll}
    \toprule
    &   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Solution to $C_k$} &   &   &   \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-5}
Problem $I_k$ & Solved $C_k$ & $x_1$ & $x_2$ & $z$ & Current & Pursue & Stored     \\
     \midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you are welcome. now i added some of-topic thoughts  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variant using the `tabularx` package to make the table automatically spread to textwidth without manually specifying the column's widths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |l|l|*3{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}|l|l|l| }
    \hline
    Problem $I_k$ & Solved $C_k$ & \multicolumn{3}{ c| }{Solution to $C_k$} & Current & Pursue & Stored\\\cline{3-5} 
    & & $x_1$ & $x_2$ & $z$ & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```